# How to react to a post using graph api and php sdk?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I can like a post given the id:

```
$makeLike = $fb->post('/' .  $valueid. '/likes',array(),  $page['access_token']);
```

but how do I react to the post, such as wow, angery, etc...?

FB docs say you can't create a reaction endpoint, but I know this isn't true as I have seen other apps do this, and it would make no sense to be able to like and not react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/reactions) says you can't.

> Creating
>
> You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.
>
> Updating
>
> You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.
>
> Deleting
>
> You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.

Comment: hmm. not convinced.          $makeLike = $fb->post('/' .  $valueid. '/reactions',array('type' => 'WOW'),  $page['access_token']); using this i get the error (#3) App must be on whitelist

Comment: They might be giving access to it to specific apps only via that whitelist, but there's no public way to at the moment.